# Problems with Wordwrap in Flashpunk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, word-wrap

For some reason, the last line of my wordwrap does not display

```
public class ShopButton extends Entity 
{

    private var callback:Function = null;
    public var buttonText:String = "";
    public var textImage:Text;
    public var picture:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 1);
    public var boxImage:Stamp;
    public var displayImage:Graphiclist;
    public var displayImage2:Graphiclist;

    public var tooltipPicture:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, 130, true, 1);
    public var tooltipBox:Stamp;
    public var tooltipText:Array = [];
    public var tooltipString:Array = [];


    public var buttonWidth:int = 100;
    public var buttonHeight:int = 100;

    private var clicked:Boolean = false;
    private var shiftClicked:Boolean = false;
    private var hovered:Boolean = false;
    private var fontSize:int = 16;

    public var label:String = "";

    public function ShopButton(x:int = 0, y:int = 0, label:String = "", callback:Function = null) 
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.label = label;
        buttonText = label;

        textImage = new Text(buttonText, 5, 5, { width:buttonWidth-10, wordWrap:true, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa" } );
        Draw.setTarget(picture);
        Draw.rectPlus(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, 0x000000, 1, true, 2, 5);
        Draw.rectPlus(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, 0xFFFF00, 1, false, 5, 5);

        boxImage = new Stamp(Assets.SHOPBUTTON);
        textImage.y = (boxImage.height / 2) - (textImage.height / 2);

        displayImage = new Graphiclist(boxImage, textImage);

        super (x, y, displayImage);

        setHitboxTo(boxImage);

        Draw.setTarget(tooltipPicture);
        Draw.rectPlus(0, 0, 150, 130, 0x000000, 1, true, 1, 0);
        Draw.rectPlus(0, 0, 150, 130, 0xFFFF00, 1, false, 5, 0);

        tooltipBox = new Stamp(Assets.SHOPBUTTONBORDER);

        updateTooltip();
    }

    public function updateTooltip():void
    {
        var minDamage:int = 0;
        var maxDamage:int = 0;
        var damageResist:int = 0;

        switch(label)
        {
            case "Purchase Ammo":
                tooltipString[0] = "";
                tooltipString[1] = "Purchase more";
                tooltipString[2] = "shurikens";
                tooltipString[3] = "";
                tooltipString[4] = "Shift + Click";
                tooltipString[5] = "To buy max";
                break;
            case "Upgrade Melee Weapon":
                minDamage = Globals.meleeDamage[0][Globals.meleeLevel];
                maxDamage = Globals.meleeDamage[1][Globals.meleeLevel];
                minDamage = minDamage * (1+(Globals.playerMeleeDamage / 100));
                maxDamage = maxDamage * (1 + (Globals.playerMeleeDamage / 100));
                tooltipString[0] = "Current Level";
                tooltipString[1] = "Damage: "
                tooltipString[2] = "" + minDamage + " - " + maxDamage;
                tooltipString[3] = "Next Level";
                if (Globals.meleeLevel < Globals.meleeMaxLevel)
                {
                    minDamage = Globals.meleeDamage[0][Globals.meleeLevel + 1];
                    maxDamage = Globals.meleeDamage[1][Globals.meleeLevel + 1];
                    minDamage = minDamage * (1+(Globals.playerMeleeDamage / 100));
                    maxDamage = maxDamage * (1 + (Globals.playerMeleeDamage / 100));
                    tooltipString[4] = "Damage: "
                    tooltipString[5] = "" + minDamage + " - " + maxDamage;
                }
                else 
                {
                    tooltipString[4] = "";
                    tooltipString[5] = "Max Level";
                }
                break;
            case "Upgrade Ranged Weapon":
                minDamage = Globals.rangedDamage[0][Globals.rangedLevel];
                maxDamage = Globals.rangedDamage[1][Globals.rangedLevel];
                minDamage = minDamage * (1+(Globals.playerRangeDamage / 100));
                maxDamage = maxDamage * (1 + (Globals.playerRangeDamage / 100));
                tooltipString[0] = "Current Level";
                tooltipString[1] = "Damage: "
                tooltipString[2] = "" + minDamage + " - " + maxDamage;
                tooltipString[3] = "Next Level";
                if (Globals.rangedLevel < Globals.rangedMaxLevel)
                {
                    minDamage = Globals.rangedDamage[0][Globals.rangedLevel + 1];
                    maxDamage = Globals.rangedDamage[1][Globals.rangedLevel + 1];
                    minDamage = minDamage * (1+(Globals.playerRangeDamage / 100));
                    maxDamage = maxDamage * (1 + (Globals.playerRangeDamage / 100));
                    tooltipString[4] = "Damage: "
                    tooltipString[5] = "" + minDamage + " - " + maxDamage;
                }
                else 
                {
                    tooltipString[4] = "";
                    tooltipString[5] = "Max Level";
                }
                break;
            case "Upgrade Armor":
                damageResist = Globals.armorDefense[Globals.armorLevel];
                damageResist = damageResist * (1 + (Globals.playerDefense / 100));
                tooltipString[0] = "Current Level";
                tooltipString[1] = "Damage Resist: "
                tooltipString[2] = "" + damageResist;
                tooltipString[3] = "Next Level";
                if (Globals.armorLevel < Globals.armorMaxLevel)
                {
                    damageResist = Globals.armorDefense[Globals.armorLevel + 1];
                    damageResist = damageResist * ( 1 + (Globals.playerDefense / 100));
                    tooltipString[4] = "Damage Resist: "
                    tooltipString[5] = "" + damageResist;
                }
                else 
                {
                    tooltipString[4] = "";
                    tooltipString[5] = "Max Level";
                }
                break;
        }

        tooltipText[0] = new Text(tooltipString[0], 0, 10, {width:150, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa"});
        tooltipText[0].x = -25;
        tooltipText[0].y -= 20;
        tooltipText[1] = new Text(tooltipString[1], 0, 30, {width:150, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa"});
        tooltipText[1].x = -25;
        tooltipText[1].y -= 20;
        tooltipText[2] = new Text(tooltipString[2], 0, 45, {width:150, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa"});
        tooltipText[2].x = -25;
        tooltipText[2].y -= 20;
        tooltipText[3] = new Text(tooltipString[3], 0, 65, {width:150, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa"});
        tooltipText[3].x = -25;
        tooltipText[3].y -= 20;
        tooltipText[4] = new Text(tooltipString[4], 0, 85, {width:150, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa"});
        tooltipText[4].x = -25;
        tooltipText[4].y -= 20;
        tooltipText[5] = new Text(tooltipString[5], 0, 100, {width:150, align:"center", size:fontSize, font:"Abscissa"});
        tooltipText[5].x = -25;
        tooltipText[5].y -= 20;

        tooltipBox.x = -25;
        tooltipBox.y = -20;

        displayImage2 = new Graphiclist(tooltipBox, tooltipText[0], tooltipText[1], tooltipText[2], tooltipText[3], tooltipText[4], tooltipText[5]);

    }

    public function click(action:String = ""):void
    {
        //trace(action);
        if (action == "Shift" && label == "Purchase Ammo" && callback != null) callback("Shift");
        else if (callback != null) callback();
    }

    override public function update():void
    {
        super.update();
        if (collidePoint(x, y, world.mouseX, world.mouseY))
        {
            if (Input.mousePressed && !Input.check(Key.SHIFT))
            {
                shiftClicked = false;
                clicked = true;
            }
            if (Input.mousePressed && Input.check(Key.SHIFT))
            {
                //trace ("Shifty");
                clicked = false;
                shiftClicked = true;
            }
            if (Input.mouseReleased && clicked) click("");
            if (Input.mouseReleased && shiftClicked) click("Shift");
            hovered = true;
        }
        else hovered = false;

        if (Input.mouseReleased) clicked = false;

        if (hovered) 
        {
            updateTooltip();
            graphic = displayImage2;
        }
        else graphic = displayImage;
    }

}
```

When I run it, it displays all but the last line of text (I guess I need a rep of 10 to post a screenshot).  For example, the first button displays "Purchase" instead of "Purchase Ammo".

Has anyone ever run into this issue before, and if so how do you get around it?

Comment: Try lowering your font size, perhaps you've crossed your button's textfield constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into some problems with word wrap. It seems that for Text class the word wrap works correctly when you specify its width and height and then set the word wrap to true and important - resizable to false.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the exact same problem, try setting the height attribute, that solved for me.